# Safari thinks it is not connected to the internet while Firefox and Chrome do

Tags: mac, safari

Mac Ventura. Over the past few months, I have been getting the constant problem that Safari stops thinking it is connected to the Internet. Tabs that are open and connected keep working but new tabs stop working. Sometimes when I am on YOUTUBE, I get a message saying I am not connected to the Internet.

Meanwhile Firefox and Chrome work fine. If My passwords were not all saved in Safari, I'd just switch.

I have to shut down the wireless connection and restart it to get Safari to start working again .... for a while.

Google search shows other people having the same problem. However, the only "solutions" are the standard clear cache or reboot that have no effect on the problem.

Apple tells me it is my VPN causing the problem but I get the same problem whether the VPN is connected or disconnected.

I've seen posts saying to disable all proxy settings. They had not been enabled on my machine.

Comment: Importing passwords from Safari to Bitwarden is pretty easy https://bitwarden.com/help/import-from-safari/ You can download the addons/plugins here https://bitwarden.com/download/ (I'd strongly recommend Firefox over Chrome) It is free (click the Personal tab) https://bitwarden.com/pricing/

Comment: Heck, if you don't want a password manager (why not?) you could simply import the Safari passwords into Firefox, then uninstall Safari https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/importing-safari-data-firefox & https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1368747